# Image distortion algorithms in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, image, algorithm, distortion

So I'm creating  distortions for for a webapp. I want to achieve some effects similiar to the photo booth app in mac. It's quite hard to find material on web. Most of the artciles (like this http://www.splashnology.com/article/pixel-distortions-with-bilinear-filtration-in-html5-canvas/4739/) describe only basics. Now, for example, I want to make the spherize or twirl effect more smooth towards the corners, but I can't find any solution.
Any help, ideas, resources?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: I know) But now I want to learn how to improve these algorithms)

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you are interested in simple effects like waves, here read http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Синусоида, it's all the ideas we were in the 8th grade (Google translation from Russian to English).

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
        <script src="../js/common.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <script>            

            addEventListener('load', function() {
                var cnv = gid('q');
                var ctx = cnv.getContext('2d');
                // характеризует сдвиг графика по оси Oy. Чем больше a, тем выше поднимается график
                var a = cnv.height / 2;
                // характеризует растяжение графика по оси Oy. Чем больше увеличивается b, тем сильнее возрастает амплитуда колебаний
                var b = 10;
                // характеризует растяжение графика по оси Ox. При увеличении c частота колебаний повышается
                var c = .05;
                // характеризует сдвиг графика по оси Ox. При увеличении d график двигается в положительном направлении оси абсцисс
                var d = 0;

                for (var i = 0; i < cnv.width; ++i) {
                    ctx.fillRect(i, ( a + b * Math.sin(c * i + d) ), 1, 1);
                }

                var cnv1 = gid('e');
                var ctx1 = cnv1.getContext('2d');
                ctx1.font = 'bold 30px Calibri';
                ctx1.fillText('Hello', 10, 30);
                var imd = ctx1.getImageData(0, 0, cnv1.width, cnv1.height);

                var cnv2 = gid('r');
                var ctx2 = cnv2.getContext('2d');
                ctx2.fillRect(0, 0, cnv2.width, cnv2.height);
                var imd1 = ctx2.getImageData(0, 0, cnv2.width, cnv2.height);
                var w = imd.width * 4;

                for (var i = 0, j, x, y, d = imd.data, d1 = imd1.data, l = d.length; i < l; i += 4) {
                    y = Math.floor(i / w);
                    x = i - w * y;   
                    j =  ( y + Math.floor( 10 * Math.sin(.01 * x) ) ) * w + x;
                    d1[j] = d[i];
                    d1[j + 1] = d[i + 1];
                    d1[j + 2] = d[i + 2];
                    d1[j + 3] = d[i + 3];
                }

        ctx2.putImageData(imd1, 0, 0);
            });

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <canvas id="q" width="140" height="40"></canvas>
        <p>График синусоиды.</p>
        <canvas id="e" width="140" height="40"></canvas>
        <p>Изображение без искажения.</p>
        <canvas id="r" width="140" height="40"></canvas>
        <p>Изображение с искажением.</p>
    </body>
</html>
```